# How to add JSON data to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json

This is my RecyclerAdapter code:

```
package com.example.sander.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Sander on 6-4-2017.
 */

public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;
    ArrayList<String> ArrayDataset;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);

            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_blah);

        }

    }

    public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<String> names){
        ArrayDataset = names;
    }

    @Override
    public RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_view, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        holder.mTextView.setText(ArrayDataset.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return ArrayDataset.size(); }
}
```

And this is my Recycler **Fragment** code:

```
package com.example.sander.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sander on 6-4-2017.
 */

public class RecycleFrame extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    GoogleMaps maps = new GoogleMaps();
    public RecycleFrame() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://test.dontstealmywag.ga/api/parkgarage.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("parkgarage");
                            for ( int i=0; i< values.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                                names.add(jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_name"));
                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });
        rq.add(stringRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle, container, false);
        RecyclerView VRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        VRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecycleAdapter adapter = new RecycleAdapter(names);
        VRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        VRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now if I'm correct. My data from my API (link can be found in the code), will be added in an `ArrayList` called "`names`", but when I run my code my `Recyclerview` is empty. How do I add my JSON data to the `RecyclerView` and display it.

(For the record if I try it with `String [] {"Example"}` it will show a card with "`Example`")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your request is async so you should call setAdapter() in onResponse(). Otherwise, because of fragment life cycle your setAdapter() method called before your request finishing. Please move RecycleAdapter(names) to onResponse block.

Comment: @iravul Thanks! It works just as you say!